# How to use lxml to find an element by text?

Tags: python, html, lxml

Assume we have the following html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/1234.html">TEXT A</a>
        <a href="/3243.html">TEXT B</a>
        <a href="/7445.html">TEXT C</a>
    <body>
</html>
```

How do I make it find the element "a", which contains "TEXT A"?

So far I've got:

```py
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(the_html_above)
e = root.find('.//a')
```

I've tried:

```py
e = root.find('.//a[@text="TEXT A"]')
```

but that didn't work, as the "a" tags have no attribute "text".

Is there any way I can solve this in a similar fashion to what I've tried?

Comment: have you tried `:contains`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are very close. Use `text()=` rather than `@text` (which indicates an attribute).

```py
e = root.xpath('.//a[text()="TEXT A"]')
```

Or, if you know only that the text contains "TEXT A",

```py
e = root.xpath('.//a[contains(text(),"TEXT A")]')
```

Or, if you know only that text starts with "TEXT A",

```py
e = root.xpath('.//a[starts-with(text(),"TEXT A")]')
```

See [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) for more on the available string functions.

---

For example,

```
import lxml.html as LH

text = '''\
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/1234.html">TEXT A</a>
        <a href="/3243.html">TEXT B</a>
        <a href="/7445.html">TEXT C</a>
    <body>
</html>'''

root = LH.fromstring(text)
e = root.xpath('.//a[text()="TEXT A"]')
print(e)
```

yields

```
[<Element a at 0xb746d2cc>]
```

Comment: That gives me SyntaxError: invalid predicate.

Comment: Right. `find`/`findAll` are simplified methods which do not allow all kinds of XPath. With the current version of lxml, `xpath` accepts XPath version 1.0.

Comment: Oops, just deleted the comment before you posted. I replaced find and findAll in my code and it works. Thank you once more :)

Comment: I get [<Element a at 0xb746d2cc>] but when i try to fetch the text i get this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 82: invalid start byte
pls help

Comment: Thanks. I was using `root.find(`… instead of `root.xpath(`….

Comment: The xpath docs linked above are long and difficult to read.  There is a really good introductory presentation [here](https://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-14/s05/lecture-4/allslides.html) with everything you need to get going.

Answer (score 10):

Another way that looks more straightforward to me:

```py
results = []
root = lxml.hmtl.fromstring(the_html_above)
for tag in root.iter():
    if "TEXT A" in tag.text
        results.append(tag)
```

Comment: Or of course `tag.text == "TEXT A"` if you're looking for the exact text