# Using LXML with Html, Requests, and ETree, it gives links, but wont let me search links for specific text

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to pull specific data out of the link provided below. When I run the code, it gives me all of the href links as expected, but when I try further testing for the same string, but using the contains syntax, it comes back as empty.

Ive checked read the docs, as well as DevHints, and everywhere I look, the "Contains" syntax is the recommended method to capture what Im looking for when all I know is that the syntax will be included, but not where or how.

Im trying to build a scraper to help a lot of people recently laid off find new work, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
from lxml import html, etree
import requests

page = requests.get('https://ea.gr8people.com/index.gp?method=cappportal.showPortalSearch&sysLayoutID=123')

# print(page.content)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

print(tree)
# Select All Nodes

AllNodes = tree.xpath("//*")

# Select Only hyperlink nodes

AllHyperLinkNodes = tree.xpath("//*/a")

# Iterate through all Node Links

for node in AllHyperLinkNodes:
        print(node.values())

print("======================================================================================================================")

# select using a condition 'contains'
# NodeThatContains = tree.xpath('//td[@class="search-results-column-left"]/text()')
NodeThatContains = tree.xpath('//*/a[contains(text(),"opportunityid")]')

for node in NodeThatContains:
        print(node.values())

# Print the link that 'contains' the text
# print(NodeThatContains[0].values())
```

Comment: Ive also looked at this page here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299978/how-to-use-lxml-to-find-an-element-by-text/14300008#14300008  and it shows almost identical syntax, especially when related to the contains statement, so Im not sure why its not working, unless it has to expressly match the text in its entirity, which mine is part of something like ...&opportunityid=XXXXXX, but Im not aware of whether or not it has to have the entire text. I dont think it does, and havent seen that anywhere that says it has to.

Comment: If "opportunityid" is in an href attribute, you should just be able to change your xpath to `//*/a[contains(@href,"opportunityid")]`.

Comment: You also shouldn't need the *...`//a[contains(@href,"opportunityid")]`

Comment: I just checked this, this also worked. Thank you very much for your assistance! It looks exceptionally clean as well in terms of output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup based solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://ea.gr8people.com/index.gp?method=cappportal.showPortalSearch&sysLayoutID=123').content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
links = [a for a in links if a.attrs.get('href') and 'opportunityid' in a.attrs.get('href')]
print('-- opportunities --')
for idx, link in enumerate(links):
    print('{}) {}'.format(idx, link))
```

Output

```
-- opportunities --
0) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=154761&amp;opportunityid=154761">
                                        2D Capture Artist - 6 month contract
                                    </a>
1) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=154426&amp;opportunityid=154426">
                                        Accounting Supervisor
                                    </a>
2) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=152147&amp;opportunityid=152147">
                                        Advanced Analyst
                                    </a>
3) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=153395&amp;opportunityid=153395">
                                        Advanced UX Researcher
                                    </a>
4) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=151309&amp;opportunityid=151309">
                                        AI Engineer
                                    </a>
5) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=150468&amp;opportunityid=150468">
                                        AI Scientist
                                    </a>
6) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=151310&amp;opportunityid=151310">
                                        AI Scientist - NLP Focus
                                    </a>
7) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=153351&amp;opportunityid=153351">
                                        AI Software Engineer (Apex Legends)
                                    </a>
8) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=152737&amp;opportunityid=152737">
                                        AI Software Engineer (Frostbite)
                                    </a>
9) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=154764&amp;opportunityid=154764">
                                        Analyste Qualité Sénior / Senior Quality Analyst
                                    </a>
10) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=153948&amp;opportunityid=153948">
                                        Animator 1
                                    </a>
11) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=151353&amp;opportunityid=151353">
                                        Applications Agreement Analyst
                                    </a>
12) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=154668&amp;opportunityid=154668">
                                        AR Analyst I
                                    </a>
13) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=153609&amp;opportunityid=153609">
                                        AR Specialist
                                    </a>
14) <a href="index.gp?method=cappportal.showJob&amp;layoutid=2092&amp;inp1541=&amp;inp1375=154773&amp;opportunityid=154773">
                                        Artiste Audio / Audio Artist
                                    </a>
```

Comment: This is ABSOLUTELY PERFECT! Thank you! Is there any documentation based on this solution that you would recommend to help me to further understand it? I know most of it, and I can interpret most of the rest, but some of these I havent seen before, like the links = portion, I wasnt aware I could do a for with an if statement with beautiful soup, more specifically with the AND statement. I tried that several times earlier and they just simply rejected my syntax, so any notes on that especially would be absolutely awesome!

Comment: I am glad to help :-). There is no 'magic' in the code - just BS API and python List Comprehension

Comment: Would you have a recommended or best practices way for me to modify the URL to concatinate it to the base URL of the page, so that the URL link is then whole, instead of partial in its current form?

The other part of my code already iterates through each page, collecting all of the information into a CSV currently, and Id like to add the job link to that file until I can make it into JSON format for an API intake on the system Im working on.

So far Ive tried print(links).lstrip to pull <a href=" off, but that didnt work for some reason.